# Chemical difference between hand sanitizer vs hand wash?

Tags: cleaning

Is there any major difference between hand sanitizer and hand wash?
Is it safe to use hand wash only alone, without use of water?

Comment: Major difference is sanitisers need not water as they need not to be washed away.

Answer (score 3):

The major practical difference is that sanitizers need not water as they need not to be washed away.

Hand sanitizers are usually ethanol or isopropanol, diluted by water and enriched eventually by a minor amount of active disinfectant and/or thickeners. When applied, part of it evaporates, rest is absorbed by skin.

Hand wash is similar to shampoo, shower gel or liquid dish washer. All of them are basically concentrated solutions of detergents, anionic ones ( typical example sodium laureth sulphate ) , cationic ones ( like cocamidopropyl betaine ) and non ionic ones. Different product classes differ in the detergent concetration, their mutual ratio and in minor and auxiliary components.

Long skin exposure to the undiluted hand wash is not desired. It is not some dark top secret of cosmetical companies. Prolonging any good effect may eventually lead to turning it into a bad effect. Long skin exposure to water is not desired either.

Practically and short term, who wants sticky fingers ? From the chemical POV and longer term, skin maceration by concentrated detergent causes extreme skin fat extraction and various related and/or consequent effects that I am not going to comment as a chemist.

All is also a question of dilution. More diluted the hand wash is, more the hand wash properties converge toward the sanitiser in context of stickyness and fat agressivity. OTOH, the sanitizing effect of hand wash would decrease with dilution. Chemists do not dare to define the boundary of yet sufficient sanitation effect.

The aggressiveness of the detergent effect usually decreases in the order

- liquid cloth wash
- liquid dish wash
- hand wash
- shampoos and shower gels
- shower gels with fatty components, having therefore a body lotion feature.

Probably nobody would say using undiluted dish washer as hand sanitiser substitute is a wise thing to do. Hand wash is significantly less harmful, but still...

Comment: *Long skin exposure to the undiluted hand wash is not desired* - is it? I never came across such a warning. Could you explain more about this / state a reference?

Comment: I do not have any handy reference, but it is not a dark top secret. Long skin exposure to water is not desired either. Anybody can do simple experiment on his/her own hands. Note that initially, there were no warnings against putting cats into microwave oven to dry them either. But some less wise Americans forced many vendors of many devices to create multipage list of what you should not do.

Answer (score 1):

From **UCLA Health**<sup>1</sup>:

> Right now, the CDC recommendation is to wash hands whenever possible.
> Hand sanitizer is more precise at killing bacteria and most viruses,
> but hand washing can effectively remove all dirt, microbes and
> chemicals on the hands. All elements of hand-washing are key—friction
> for removing debris, soap to emulsify dirt, chemicals and microbes and
> running water to remove the debris.

And **Deb Blog**<sup>2</sup>:

> When considering the effectiveness of hand washing and sanitizer use,
> we need to recognize that human pathogens and opportunistic pathogens,
> exist in multidimensional continuum in terms of survival, chemical
> resistance to antimicrobial compounds, and efficacy of hand washing
> etc.  Because each microorganism exists in their own multifaceted
> conditions for existence and survival, there can be no “one size fits
> all” approach to control and prevention of disease in respect to hand
> hygiene.
>
> At one end of the hand washing efficacy continuum are viruses that are
> harder to remove from hands than bacteria and the even larger parasite
> cysts and eggs.  This is because size matters.  The smaller the
> pathogen, the more easily trapped in the cracks and creases of our
> epidermis and our stratum corneum.  Here we need to realize that
> aggressive or “good quality hand washing” is more critical in going
> after viruses as opposed to our usually larger prey, bacteria.
> Multiple studies indicate that in addition to surfactant action,
> friction (good old fashioned elbow grease) at the rinsing stage is
> perhaps the most critical period of hand washing in its ability to
> dislodge viruses from skin surfaces. That said, you only have so many
> highly aggressive hand washings (hand washing events) a day to remove
> viruses before hands begin to dry out and become sore, even when using
> the gentlest of soaps.
>
> Hand washing men and women. In another continuum of antimicrobial
> action we have organisms at one end like C. difficile whose spores are
> entirely resistant to alcohol hand sanitizers (as discussed in the C.
> diff blog).  And indeed, norovirus is not far from C. diff in terms of
> chemical resistance. To protect hands from these compounds we must
> rely on use of the proper gloves where appropriate. For norovirus
> generally considered fairly resistant to chemical sanitizers there is
> accumulating evidence that efficacy of high tech sanitizers is as good
> as an average or substandard hand wash.  This should be kept in mind
> when trying to balance skin health with risk reduction and frequent
> aggressive hand washing has begun to degrade skin barrier function.
>
> Fortunately at the opposite end of the continuum of antimicrobial
> action are a very large number of microorganisms, bacteria, viruses
> and fungi that are easily killed by hand sanitizers. Here hand washing
> while still necessary, is less important when no visible soil is
> present and hand sanitizers can be relied upon not only to kill these
> bugs but also provided much needed emollients back to the skin
> surface. Skin actually becomes healthier the more the latest
> generation of hand sanitizers are used.
>
> Remember, use of sanitizer in healthcare and food venues was
> implemented to protect hands from the potentially damaging effects of
> too frequent hand washing (and drying).  We are not always going to
> know which microbial hazard we are up against.

**References**:

1. https://connect.uclahealth.org/2020/03/10/handwashing-vs-hand-sanitizer-whats-the-difference/
2. https://info.debgroup.com/blog/bid/270757/hand-washing-or-hand-sanitizer-which-is-better-and-why

**For a detailed analysis and description, check out this**:

Andreas F. Widmer, Replace Hand Washing with Use of a Waterless Alcohol Hand Rub?, Clinical Infectious Diseases, Volume 31, Issue 1, **July 2000**, Pages 136–143, DOI: [10.1086/313888](https://academic.oup.com/cid/article/31/1/136/317796)